# Why do x&1==0 and !(x&1) not yield the same results in an if statement in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, bitwise-operators

I had both of these conditions inside an `if` statement to check if `x` was even or odd, but the `!(x&1)` seemed to execute the body of the `if` in case of an even `x`, while `x&1==0` didn't execute it.

I expected both to give 0 considering `1 & 0` is `0` and 1 in 32 or 64 bit representations will be `000..01` and if, say, `x` is something like `10010101100` (even), then their bit-wise and should yield 0. Hence, I'm still not sure why `!(x&1)` works. Please correct me if I am wrong in anywhere.
Thank you.

Comment: What was the compiler warning on `if(x&1==0)`?

Answer (score 5):

It's just an operator precedence issue that you're facing.

In the expression `x&1 == 0`, the `==` operator has the highest precedence; it will be evaluated before the `&` operator. As a consequence, `x&1 == 0` will evaluate to `x & (1 == 0)`, which evaluates to `x & 0` (always equal to 0).

You can find a reliable [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) table on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com).

You can use parentheses to solve your issue: `(x & 1) == 0`

Comment: cppreference is not "the official" table. Its a good reference, but the official one is the standard